# How to use Angular models to parse JSON objects with generic names?

Tags: json, typescript

I'm creating a model into an Angular project to parse some JSON data for a service.

the JSON file returns information like this:

```
[
    {
        "bronze": [
            {
                "name": "Pontua\u00e7\u00e3o",
                "now": "7.000",
                "enabling": "1.800",
                "icon": "score",
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Cancelamento",
                "now": "2.5%",
                "enabling": "5.0%",
                "icon": "cancellation",
                "status": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "silver": [
            {
                "name": "Pontua\u00e7\u00e3o",
                "now": "7.000",
                "enabling": "4.000",
                "icon": "score",
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Cancelamento",
                "now": "2.5%",
                "enabling": "5.0%",
                "icon": "cancellation",
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Assinatura Digital",
                "now": "79.5%",
                "enabling": "5.0%",
                "icon": "cancellation",
                "status": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to tell Angular that the object's name doesn't matter, like so:

```
export interface Checklist {
   anyObject: ChecklistItems[];
}

export interface ChecklistItems {
    name:     string;
    now:      string;
    enabling: string;
    icon:     string;
    status:   number;
}
```

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually a typescript question where the answer is using index signatures:

```
interface Checklist {
  [key: string]: ChecklistItems[];
}
```

Im this way - you can have any key as string, with the values you've specified.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've changed the post tags to JSON and Typescript to correct the post too.